# Opening submenu doesn't push down rest of content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with my mobilemenu (width < 1220px)
When opening the submenu by clicking the + next to the menu item, the next layer is displayed. However it overlaps with the rest of the menu and doesn't push it down.
How can I achieve this?
There is a codepen attached.
https://codepen.io/bvonr/pen/oNwOjgp
thanks for any help

```js
(function () {
  var change = document.querySelector(".burger-container"),
    box = document.querySelector(".mobilenavigation"),
    hider = document.querySelector(".bodyandfooter");

  change.onclick = function () {
    change.classList.toggle("menu-opened");
    box.classList.toggle("menu-opened");
    hider.classList.toggle("menu-opened");
  };
})();

$(".secondLayer > .plus-button > ul").parent().parent().addClass("hasChildren");

$(".secondLayer").click(function () {
  $(this).find(".plus-button").toggleClass("open");
  $(this).find(".plus-button").parent().parent().toggleClass("expand");
});
```

```css
/* Menu generell */
.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #24603c;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 0px rgb(41 41 41 / 25%);
}
.section {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobilenavigation a:hover {
  color: lightgrey;
}
/* Login Button Position*/
.login-container {
  float: right;
  height: 70px;
}
/* Login Button Style */
.login-container button {
  /* font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif; */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #24603c;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  margin: 9px 25px;
}
/* Login Button beim Hovern*/
.login-container button:hover {
  color: lightgrey;
}
/* Login Popup bei Klick einblenden */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
/* Popup Box Design */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 4% auto 15% auto;
  border: none;
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  color: #24603c;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Login Popup Eingabefelder Style */
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 375px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
/* Login-Popup Inhalt zentrieren */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
/* Style Logo im Login Popup */
.avatar {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
/* Popup schlie&#65533;en Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  color: #24603c;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Popup schlie&#65533;en Button bei Hover */
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Animation Popup einblenden */
/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  animation: zoom 0.6s forwards;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
/* Login Popup Anmelden Button Desgin */
input.loginanmelden {
  background-color: #24603c;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 96%;
}
/* Login Popup Anmelden Button Hover Desgin */
input.loginanmelden:hover {
  color: lightgrey;
}
/* Login Popup Passwort vergessen Link Desgin */
#formlogin a {
  color: #24603c;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: none;
}
/* Login Popup Passwort vergessen Hover Link Desgin */
#formlogin a:hover {
  color: red;
}
#formlogin input {
  height: 40px;
}
#formlogin > br:nth-child(11),
#formlogin > br:nth-child(12),
#formlogin > br:nth-child(17) {
  display: none;
}
/* Nur Desktop Menu */
@media (min-width: 1023px) {
  .section {
    height: 80px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .logo * {
    height: 70px;
  }
  .navbar {
    height: 70px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .mobilenavigation {
    width: 75%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .menuliste {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .menuli1 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .menuli1 > a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 25px 10px 5px 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
  }
  .header a:hover {
    color: lightgray;
  }
  .menulist {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 3px rgba(41, 41, 41, 0.25);
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .menuli1:hover > .menulist {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .menulevel1 {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .menulevel1 a {
    display: block;
    color: #24603c;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .menulevel1 > ul {
    left: 180px;
    margin-top: -36px;
    list-style: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .menulevel1:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .login {
    width: 13%;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 70px;
  }
  .material-icons {
    font-size: 19px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  .burger-container {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* Nur Responsive/Smartphone Menu */
@media (max-width: 1022px) {
  .header {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .logo * {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar,
  .login {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .login-container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: solid #24603c 1px;
  }
  .login {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99),
      opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  }
  .mobilenavigation .login {
    transition-delay: 0.21s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened .login {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    transition-delay: 0.55s;
  }
  .login-container button {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    color: #24603c;
  }
  .mobilenavigation {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("LogoGrau.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-size: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }
  .burger-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  #burger {
    width: 18px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: -4px auto 0;
    top: 50%;
  }
  .bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
  .bar.topBar {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  .bar.btmBar {
    transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  .burger-container.menu-opened {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  .burger-container.menu-opened #burger .bar {
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }
  .burger-container.menu-opened #burger .bar.topBar {
    transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .burger-container.menu-opened #burger .bar.btmBar {
    transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  .bodyandfooter.menu-opened {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .mobilenavigation a {
    color: #24603c;
    float: left;
  }
  .menuli1 > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .menuliste > .menuli1 {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: solid #24603c 1px;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .menuli1 i {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  .mobilenavigation ul.menuliste li.menuli1 {
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99),
      opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  }
  ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.49s;
  }
  ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.42s;
  }
  ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.35s;
  }
  ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.28s;
  }
  ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 0.21s;
  }
  ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 0.14s;
  }
  ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 0.07s;
  }
  .mobilemenu.menu-opened {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
  }

  .mobilenavigation ul.menuliste li.menuli1 {
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99),
      opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  }
  .mobilenavigation ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.49s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.42s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.35s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.28s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 0.21s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 0.14s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 0.07s;
  }
  .mobilemenu.menu-opened {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened ul.menuliste li.menuli1 {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.27s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.34s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.41s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.48s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 0.55s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 0.62s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened ul.menuliste li.menuli1:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 0.69s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened .login ul.menuliste li.menuli1 {
    transition-delay: 0.76s;
  }
  .plus-button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
  }
  .plus-button:hover .plus-icon,
  .plus-button:hover .plus-icon:before {
    background: lightgrey;
  }
  .plus-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #24603c;
    border-radius: 0.75em;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: -4px;
  }
  .plus-icon:before {
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 0.75em;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    transform-origin: 10px center;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 90deg);
    background-color: #24603c;
  }
  .open.plus-button .plus-icon:before {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  .hasChildren .plus-button {
    display: block;
  }
  .plus-button > .menulist {
    display: none;
  }
  .expand > .menulist {
    display: block;
  }
  .menulist {
    position: relative;
    clear: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="mobilenavigation">
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="menuliste">

          <li class="menuli1">
            <a href="?module=start">CLUB</a>
            <div class="secondLayer">
              <div class="plus-button">
                <div class="plus-icon"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="menulist">
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="Ueber-Uns">ÜBER UNS</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="Mitgliedschaft">MITGLIEDSCHAFT</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="Kontakt">KONTAKT</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="Gastronomie">GASTRONOMIE</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="Vorstand">VORSTAND</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="Partner">UHLEN-PARTNER</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="download">Download</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?module=events">CLUB-KALENDER</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=platzbuchung_uebersicht&filterplaetze=48,109">RAUMBELEGUNG</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=start_forum">FORUM</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menuli1">
            <a href="?module=profile">test</a>
            <div class="secondLayer">
              <div class="plus-button">
                <div class="plus-icon"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="menulist">
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=profile_edit">PROFIL</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=tasks_freigabe">Freigaben</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=start_news&cmd=list">ARTIKEL</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=members_gruppenleiter">GRUPPENLEITER</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=tasks_meine">Meine Aufgaben</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?module=data">DATENABLAGE</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=profile_uebersicht">Übersicht</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel1">
                <a href="#">Downloads</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel1">
                <a href="#">
                  Verweise
                  <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menulist">
                  <li class="menulevel2">
                    <a class=" " href="?action=profile_mailarchiv">Meine Mails</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menuli1">
            <a href="?module=admin">ADMIN</a>
            <div class="secondLayer">
              <div class="plus-button">
                <div class="plus-icon"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="menulist">
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=admin_overview">ÜBERBLICK</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=admin_basis">BASISKONFIG</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=admin_optionen">Optionen</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel1">
                <a href="#">
                  Vorlagen
                  <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menulist">
                  <li class="menulevel2">
                    <a class=" " href="?action=admin_mailtemplates">Mail</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="menulevel2">
                    <a class=" " href="?action=admin_pdftemplates">PDF</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="menulevel2">
                    <a class=" " href="?action=admin_static">HTML</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="menulevel2">
                    <a class=" " href="?action=admin_antraege">Anträge</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=admin_rollen">ROLLEN</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=admin_listen">Flexible Listen</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=admin_backup">Backup</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?action=admin_wunsch">SUPPORT</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menulevel1">
                <a class=" " href="?module=tasks">
                  Aufgaben
                  <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menulist">
                  <li class="menulevel2">
                  <li class="menulevel2">
                    <a class=" " href="Buchungs-Freigaben">Buchungs-Freigaben</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="menulevel2">
                    <a class=" " href="?action=tasks_freigabe">OFFEN</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                    <a href="#">Auswertung</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="login">

        <ul class="menuliste">
          <li class="menuli1">
            <a href="?logout">
              LOGOUT

              <i class="material-icons">logout</i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="burger-container">
      <div id="burger">
        <div class="bar topBar"></div>
        <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="modal-wrapper" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('modal-wrapper').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Dialog schlie&#64258;en">
          &times;</span>
        <img src="files/layout/Logo.png" alt="Logo" class="avatar" />
        <div class LoginDialog>
          <BR>
          <A id="logoutlink" HREF="./?logout" TARGET="_top">
            <IMG SRC="../admin/img/logout.png" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16" BORDER="0">
            Logout
          </A>
          <BR>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="files/layout/Burger.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="files/layout/LoginScript.js"></script>
  <script>
    function secondMenuLevel() {
      var expandsecond = document.getElementsByClasName("secondLayer");
      expandsecond.classList.toggle("open");
    }
  </script>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While trying to simplify the problem, the problem disappeared. So its just an error in the CSS that I am gonna have to find now. Thank you for your help! It really is appreciated. 
Ill add the simplified codepen just in case someone is curious
https://codepen.io/bvonr/pen/oNwOjgp

Answer (score 0):

The submenu need the CSS property `position: absolute;`

That should make not push the rest of the menu down.

My bad is not working in your code, probably some other part is conflicting.

In theory the parent needs `position:relative;` and the child `position: absolute;` to create that positioning.

Comment: I had tried this in my case it would be .menulist { position: absolute;}
Didn't help.
menulist is the second ul (ul li ul)

Comment: I just edited the comment before seeing yours, check if it helps. I can't think in anything else, has to be related with the position property.

Comment: Maybe try to create a smaller example with that problem, there is so much CSS code to review everything.

Comment: with position: relative and position: absolute on parent and child respectively I had no success. I even tried !important to make sure there are no conflicts. 
I will create a smaller example. The code was taken from my website and is huge and hard to check.